# Copy the row value from A:F where it indicates "This is not a date format" and paste the values in a specific column

Tags: excel, vba, loops

In my code, it identifies every value in the column A  "This is a date format" and  "This is not a date format". But i need it to copy the value from A:F in the row that it states  "This is not a date format" and paste it in specific cell above it like. Offset(-1, 2). Also delete the row of the cell 'That is not a date format' after the value copied. Any ideas thanks. Below is my code:

```
  Dim strDate As String


 Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
 
 Set rng = Range("A2:A18")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")

    For Each cell In rng
    MsgBox (cell.Value)
      
    strDate = cell.Value
    
    If IsDate(strDate) Then
        MsgBox "This is a date format"
        
        
        Else
        MsgBox "This is not a date format"
        
           
        'copy cell from A:E
        
    Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":F" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
    
    
    
    'Paste selected and copied in specific cell in offset(Row, Column)
    
    
    Range("K" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(-1, 2).PasteSpecial
  
        
        'copy cell from A:E
      
        
    
    
         'Paste selected and copied in specific cell in offset(Row, Column)
         
         
         
         
    End If
    Next cell
    
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to copy the values in the rows that don't have a date in `Column A` and move them to the row above starting at `Column M`?

Comment: yes exactly and delete the respective row that do not have date after the copy and paste value

Comment: You will need to loop from `Row 18` to `Row 2` or you will skip rows when you delete a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It works for all the A:A range (with data). If you need only up to A18, change `lastRow = 18`:

```
Sub testCopyNotDate_DeleteRow()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, strDate As String, rngDel As Range
  Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

   Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 
   For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Not IsDate(sh.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
            sh.Range("A" & i & ":F" & i).Copy Destination:=sh.Range("A" & i).Offset(-1, 2)
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = sh.Range("A" & i)
            Else
                Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Range("A" & i))
            End If
        End If
   Next i
   If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

It would be very fast (for big ranges) deleting the rows at once...

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer the code works. But it skip rows when I delete a row. I need to make the loop when it delete it -1 the loop. it is possible?

Comment: @gpo limited: I do not understand what you mean... The code does not care about any (previous) deleted row. It will process all existing rows between the second one and the last having data. What do you mean by "I need to make the loop when it delete it "? Would you like it to be an event (sheet change event). to fire when a row is deleted and do its job? If not, can you clearly formulate your need, from this point of view?

Answer (score 2):

Try this basic code to loop from the last row to the first row, copy the row if the first cell is not a date, and paste the data to the row above the current row starting at column M; then delete the current row.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1") 'Id your workbook and worksheet using a `With` statement
    For x = 18 To 1 Step -1 'loop through your rows from the last to the first
        'Check if the data in column A of the current row is not a date
        If IsDate(Range("A" & x)) = False Then
            'Copy the range from columns A:F on the current row and paste on the row above starting at column M
            .Range("A" & x & ":F" & x).Copy .Range("M" & x - 1)
            'Delete the current row
            .Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next x 'Loop to the next row
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy And Delete

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyAndDelete()
  
    Const wsName As String = "Feuil1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = "A"
    Const srcCol As Variant = "A"
    Const tgtCol As Variant = "M"
    Const NumOfCells As Long = 6
    Const RowOff As Long = -1
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Calculate Last Row (or not).
    Dim LastRow As Long
    ' Either calculate LastRow (usually),
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Or just use 18:
    'LastRow = 18
    
    ' Check if there is any data.
    If LastRow < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Calculate Column Offset.
    Dim ColOff As Long
    ColOff = ws.Columns(tgtCol).Column - ws.Columns(srcCol).Column
    
    ' Define Criteria Range.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, srcCol), _
                                         ws.Cells(LastRow, srcCol))
    
    ' Loop through cells in Criteria Column.
    Dim URng As Range, cell As Range, varDate As Variant
    For Each cell In rng
        varDate = cell.Value
        If Not IsDate(varDate) Then
            GoSub copyCells
            GoSub collectCells
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Test with hidden.
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ' When tested, outcomment the previous and uncomment the following line.
    'If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireRow.Delete

Exit Sub

copyCells:
    ' Either (for values only)(faster):
    cell.Offset(RowOff, ColOff).Resize(, NumOfCells).Value _
      = cell.Resize(, NumOfCells).Value
    ' Or (including formats, formulas ...)(slower):
    'cell.Resize(, NumOfCells).Copy _
      cell.Offset(RowOff, ColOff).Resize(, NumOfCells)
    Return

collectCells:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, cell)
    Else
        Set URng = cell
    End If
    Return
    
End Sub
```